# Render kendo grid inside template results in error

Tags: javascript, templates, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use an external kendo template. I want to render a grid inside the template.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">

<div id="grid"
     data-role="grid"
     data-columns="[
        { 'field': 'Name', 'attributes': { 'title': '#=Description#' } }
     ]"    
     data-bind="source: Items">
</div>

</script>
```

This works as long as I omit the '#'. If I include '#' (in the example for the title attribute), it results in an a invalid template error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the `#` or the template engine will try to evaluate that statement. As showed in [this doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#hash-literals) you can try these escaping methods:

```
{ 'title': '\\\\#=Description\\\\#' }
```

or

```
{ 'title': '\\#=Description\\#' }
```